# Agregar imagen en una columna de tabla de rdlc report viewer si cumple condicion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, imagen, reportviewer, rdlc

Tengo un reporte en report viewer, windows form visual 2019 c#, tengo una tabla que generalmente es de detalle de venta. quisiera añadir una columna que muestre una imagen en la fila si un campo de la fila cumple una condición.

digamos que ya carga mi reporte con el detalle de venta, pero si el producto tiene, supongamos, precio 0, a su derecha aparezca la imagen que esta precargada o incrustada en el informe.

necesito alguna solucion o ayuda.
quiza agrengando una expression

`IIF(field!Precio=0,'Aqui debe carga la imgen',nothing)`

algo asideberia ser el codigo de expression.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es trabajar con  la propiedad visibilidad del cuadro de la imagen

```
IIF(field!Precio=0,true,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una imagen en la columna de la tabla y en las propiedades de la imagen definir una condición para mostrar la imagen que corresponda a esa condición:
Ejemplo:

```
=IIF(Fields!VALOR.Value<Fields!MINIMO.Value,"File:C:\_imgtmp\fazul.jpg",IIF(Fields!VALOR.Value>fields!MAXMO.Value,"File:C:\_imgtmp\fred.jpg","File:C:\_imgtmp\fverde.PNG"))
```

Obviamente se pueden tener en un directorio y llamarlas por su path desde ahi...